# show geojson data in leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I loaded a geojson file into the leaflet. And I used the following code for this:

```
$.getJSON(geojson, function (json) {
                    console.log(typeof json)
                    console.log(json)
                    // somethings else .....
```

The output of this code is as follows:

type : object

json: [json image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYL6P.png)

Now I want to add this geojson to the map. And I used the following code, but it doesn't add anything:

```
json.addTo(map)
```

how can i add this geojson to map???

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly you need to explicitely create a geoJSON layer within Leaflet and pass your geoJSON data to it.

Codewise it would look kinda like this:

```
L.geoJSON(geoJson).addTo(map)
```

Comment: This code displays the following error: Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.

Comment: Surely you'll need to pass a corresponding GeoJSON object within the brackets, the "json" I put there is basically a placeholder, not necessarily bound to the json object you have in your code